# Повторно не могу обратиться к файлу

Tags: python, файлы, copy

у меня такая проблема всплыла. Программа представляет из себя простой клиент - сервер. После того как сервер получает дату от клиента, он сохраняет файл с именем tempFile, когда приходят следующие данные файл перезаписывается. Затем парсит, определяет что это за файл, организовывает каскад папок, и в последнюю папку копирует временный файл. В итоге, в первый раз все отрабатывает так как нужно, но когда приходят следующие данные вылетает ошибка :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'output/tempFille.txt' -> 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Client-server_V.1.1\\Database\\29\\2021\\06\\17\\10-28/_S!.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\main.py", line 176, in <module>
    newthread.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\main.py", line 140, in run
    a.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\main.py", line 99, in run
    shutil.move("output/tempFille.txt",hourPath +'/'+'_S!'+".txt")
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 820, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/tempFille.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

если открыть папку с этим временным файлам то он там есть. Почему то питон его не находит. пробовал ставить задержки, все равно не находит. Не понимаю с чем это связана, и куда копать.

Вот код

```
    import socket
from threading import Thread
import os
import shutil
import glob
import sys
import datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime

# from openyfail.timr import now
from datetime import date

TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
Path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1'
count = 0
swit = 0


class tempcopy():
    def __init__(self, line):

        self.line = line

    def run(self):
        print("tempcopy_run")
        # adding tempfile tj strain folder
        list_of_files=[]
        print(self.line[10:12])
        if self.line[10:12] == "30":
            os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\Database\29")
            list_of_files = glob.glob("*\*\*\*")
            print(list_of_files)
        if self.line[10:12] == "32":
            os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\Database\31")
            list_of_files = glob.glob("*\*\*\*")
        if list_of_files:
            latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
            print(latest_file)


            """rewriting file"""

            time.sleep(1)
            shutil.copy(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output"+"/"+"tempFille.txt",latest_file + '/'+ '_T!' + ".txt")




class addFolder():
    def __init__(self, data,count):

        self.data = data
        self.count=count

    def run(self):

        # print('1111111111111111111')
        print(self.data)
        print('2222222222222')
        PathData = os.path.join(Path, 'Database')
        if not os.path.exists(PathData):
            os.mkdir(PathData)
            print(PathData)

        ID_Path = os.path.join(PathData, self.data[10:12])
        if not os.path.exists(ID_Path):
            os.mkdir(ID_Path)
            print(ID_Path)


        now = datetime.now()
        year = now.strftime("%Y")
        yearPath = os.path.join(ID_Path, year)
        if not os.path.exists(yearPath):
            os.mkdir(yearPath)
            print(yearPath)

        month = now.strftime("%m")
        monthPath = os.path.join(yearPath, month)
        if not os.path.exists(monthPath):
            os.mkdir(monthPath)
            print(monthPath)

        day = now.strftime("%d")
        dayPath = os.path.join(monthPath, day)
        if not os.path.exists(dayPath):
            os.mkdir(dayPath)
            print(dayPath)

        hour = now.strftime("%H-%M")
        hourPath = os.path.join(dayPath, hour)
        os.mkdir(hourPath)
        print(hourPath)
        time.sleep(2)
            # shutil.move("output/tempFille.txt",hourPath +'/'+year+month+day+hour+dot+minute+'_S!'+".txt")
        shutil.copy("output/tempFille.txt",hourPath +'/'+'_S!'+".txt")
        # os.remove("output/tempFille.txt")
        #     print(hourPath +'/'+year+month+day+hour+dot+minute+'.'+"txt")




class ClientThread():

    def __init__(self, ip, port, sock, count):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        self.count = count
        print(" New thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port))

    def run(self):

        with open(os.path.join(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output", 'tempFille' + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
            while True:
                data = self.sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                if not data:
                    f.close()
                    print("++++++++++++++")
                    break
                line = data.strip()
                f.write(line)
        self.sock.close()
        print("___________________________________")
        time.sleep(5)
        word_strain_1 = 'Sensor ID  29'
        word_strain_2 = 'Sensor ID  31'
        word_temp_1 = 'Sensor ID    30'
        word_temp_2 = 'Sensor ID    32'
        print(os.path.isfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output\tempFille.txt"))
        l = open(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output\tempFille.txt", "r")
        for line in l:
            if not line.find(word_strain_1):
                print("strein_1")
                l.close()
                a=addFolder(word_strain_1,self.count)
                a.run()
                break
                # addFolder(word_strain_1)
            elif not line.find(word_strain_2):
                print("Strain_2")
                l.close()
                a = addFolder(word_strain_2,self.count)
                a.run()
                break
                # addFolder()
            elif not line.find(word_temp_1):
                l.close()
                print("temp_1")
                b=tempcopy(word_temp_1)
                b.run()
                break

            elif not line.find(word_temp_2):
                print("temp_2")
                l.close()
                b=tempcopy(word_temp_2)
                b.run()
                break
        time.sleep(2)
tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print('Got connection from ', (ip, port))
    count = count + 1
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, conn, count)
    newthread.run()
    print(count)
```

Comment: Первое что бросается в глаза хотя и не решает Вашей проблемы при использовании `with` `f.close()` не нужен.  Ругается он что нет файла в директории, скорее всего или файла там просто нет, или путь неправильный.

Comment: Путь верен. Так как первый раз программа отрабатывает корректно. А файл если смотреть в папку там есть(из второй парии данных). Может он пишет файл и не успевает закрыть файл, и пытается его копировать ?

Comment: А ничего, что вы там гуляете по директориям? Например, `os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\Database\29")`. При этом файл создаёте по абсолютному пути `open(os.path.join(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output", 'tempFille' + '.txt'), 'w')`. А потом с файлом работаете по относительному пути `shutil.copy("output/tempFille.txt",...`. Вообще, менять текущий каталог - плохая идея. Прибегать к этому надо только в крайнем случае. А вот **всегда** работать с файлами используя абсолютные пути - это хорошая идея.

Comment: а не дело в обратном слэше "output/tempFille.txt"?

Comment: @DickDikins Сомневаюсь, мне кажется оба варианта слешей можно использовать. Вот можно ли разные слеши использовать одновременно... Но вроде вы используете, и ничего

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня была похожа ситуация когда работал на винде и тоже что то было со слешами проблемы. И решил использовать одного формата.
И все же мне кажется проблема вот тут 
"shutil.copy(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client-server_V.1.1\output"+"/"+"tempFille.txt",latest_file + '/'+ '_T!' + ".txt")"
в пути по факту разные слэши



ВЫВОД:
#latest_file=str(12)
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Client-server_V.1.1\\output/tempFille.txt', '12/_T!.txt"

Comment: Допустим вы правы, сейчас переделаю слэши, но все же остается вопрос, почему первую пачку данных он нормально принемает?